# CRAN submission missing imports

Tags: r, devtools, cran

I'm submitting [fitbitScraper](https://github.com/corynissen/fitbitScraper) to CRAN via `devtools` and the check comes out clean. But the CRAN maintainer is telling me I have this:

```
* checking R code for possible problems ... NOTE
get_activity_data: no visible global function definition for ‘as’
get_daily_data: no visible global function definition for ‘as’
get_intraday_data: no visible global function definition for ‘as’
get_premium_export: no visible global function definition for ‘as’
get_premium_export: no visible global function definition for
  ‘read.csv’
get_sleep_data: no visible global function definition for ‘as’
get_weight_data: no visible global function definition for ‘as’
Undefined global functions or variables:
  as read.csv
```

I've submitted before without issue. Aren't `as` and `read.csv` both contained in standard packages that need not be included in the NAMESPACE file?

Comment: The `as` function is from the `methods` package and `read.csv` is from `utils`